# Including header files recursively for syntastic

Tags: c++, vim, syntastic

I'm working with a C++ project and trying to configure it to use syntastic. In my project I have a nested directory structure of header files (The actual nested structure is much worse, this is an example).

```
--libs    
    |---dir1
         |---foo1.h    
    |---dir2
         |---foo2.h
         |---foo3.h
         |---dir3
               |---foo4.h
```

I have included the lib files in my .vimrc file using:

> let g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs = [ 'libs/']

I assumed this would take all the header files recursively, but it doesn't. In the code, syntastic complains with the error 'no such file or directory found'.

When I explicitly change the variable to refer to a specific directory:

> let g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs = [ 'libs/dir2/dir3/']

**it works.**

My questions:

1. How do you configure syntastic so that it includes header files of a set of directories recursively?
2. How do you do this for multiple projects? Always editing the .vimrc as I switch the project I'm working on doesn't sound right. I believe there must be a better way.

EDIT:

I didn't mention that in my .vimrc, the following options are present for syntastic:

```
let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs = ['libs/dir2/dir3', 'libs/dir2 ]
let g:syntastic_cpp_check_header = 1
let g:syntastic_cpp_remove_include_errors = 1
```

Comment: Have you tried `let g:syntastic_cpp_check_header = 1`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have added the config options I had to the questions now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can include all the directories to be searched for header files per project in the project root directory in a file `.syntastic_cpp_config`. The format for doing so would the same as providing the `-I` directives to the compiler.

For your case it means:

- Create a file `.syntastic_cpp_config` under `sources` (assuming that's where your code is and `sources` is at a same depth level in the directory hierarchy as `libs`).
- Put the following lines in it:

  `-Ilibs/dir1`

  `-Ilibs/dir2`

  `-Ilibs/dir2/dir3`
- Note the the flags are 1 per line.
- This way you don't have to have all the include directories in your `.vimrc`.

You can have a different file to hold this custom configuration per project, specified by the `.vimrc` global variable `g:syntastic_cpp_config_file`, eg

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_config_file = '.my_custom_include_file_for_syntastic'
```

Syntastic will check each source directory and upwards until it finds this file and then use it for producing its output.

See the [Syntastic wiki page](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/wiki/(v3.1.0)---C--:---gcc),
 [Old link](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/C--%3A---gcc) for more details.

Comment: This is out of date as of a [2018 May 24 update](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues/2179). `.syntastic_cpp_config` is no longer "magic" and you must explicitly set with `let g:syntastic_cpp_config_file = ...`

Comment: Maybe I'm being pedantic, and this might be a wrong place to mention/ask this, but: Is it considered clean to have a file in the project folder just for this purpose? While it could be added to `.gitignore` for a project you're working on, I would not expect other developers to also be using Syntastic.

Comment: But if others are also using Syntastic it would be helpful for them as well. And there is no harm if they're not; it is a dotfile after all.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question with little luck. However, I've found that if I use the quotation mark style header includes, syntactic will appropriately check the folders and not issue warnings. For example, if you're working on foo2.cpp,

```
#include "dir3/foo4.h"
#include "../dir1/foo1.h"
```

Save bracket includes for standard libs and any libs you feel like hardcoding into vim.