# include <header> path and starting point

Tags: c++, vim, syntastic

I have a problem similar to this [Including header files recursively for syntastic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622992/including-header-files-recursively-for-syntastic) except my directory structure is a lot more complex so I'm not sure where to place the config file.

the .cpp file I'm editing (let's name it myfile.cpp) looks like this

```
#include <path/to/fileA.h>
#include <path/to/another/fileB.h>
...
```

and my the directory structure looks something like this:

```
program
|-include
  |-path
    |-to
      |-fileA.h
      |-another
        |-fileB.h
|-modules
  |-module1
    |-myfile.cpp
|-src
```

Moreover the `make` command is run from a directory on the same level as program (program-out) but I guess this has nothing to do with it.

So the question is: where should I put my config file containing the -I flag? which directory should I pass as parameter? Also considering that my include directives make use of <> and not ""

//EDIT
Currently my config file contains the following

```
-Iinclude
-I../include
-I../../include
-I../../../include
```

and I placed a copy in `program`, `program/src`, `program/modules/module1` and also in a few folder inside `program-out` prepending `program` to `include`

But it still doesn't work

Comment: I usually to pass in the root of the include folder so that everyone has a common base and there's only one setting to mess with.

Comment: @user4581301 so you suggest that I only write -Iinclude in the config file and place it in every folder until it works?

Comment: Write a single config file, in the root of your project. Read `:h syntastic-config-format` and `:h syntastic-debug`. Better yet don't use syntastic for linting C++ projects, specialized plugins such as [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) are much better suited for that.

Comment: Thanks @lcd047 `:h syntastic-debug` is something I was looking for. So the path is correctly added, but the error still shows up. Btw I'm using both Syntastic and YCM, i thought YCM don't show errors. I started here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237817/configuring-vim-for-c